# Delay start of force simulation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to delay the start of a force simulation by about 2 seconds. How do I do this? I feel like you should be able to say "if tick < n, don't start" or something like that... but I do not understand how or even if this is possible. I have reviewed the documentation but don't know.

Here is the code I am working with if that matters.

```
          var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
          .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(33))
          .force('x', d3.forceX().x(function(d) {
            return d.xx;
          }))
          .force('y', d3.forceY().y(function(d) {
            return d.yy;
          }))
          .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
            return d.radius;
          }))
          .on('tick', ticked);




         function ticked() {
          var u = d3.select('svg')
            .selectAll('text')
            .filter(function(d, i) { return i != 0; })
            .data(data);

          u.enter()
            .append('text')
            .merge(u)
            .text(function(d) { return d.t; })
        .attr("fill","rgb(200,101,200)")    
        .attr('x', function(d) {
              return d.x;
            })
            .attr('y', function(d) {
              return d.y;
            })


          u.exit().remove();
        }
```

Comment: Not related to the issue: did you read my comment in your previous question? Why are you using this slow and awkward code?

Comment: I did see it. I only just found out about d3 three days ago. I found this code in a tutorial and was too busy thinking about the things I want to do and figure out to focus on suboptimal code at the moment

Comment: The example you linked is not just *"suboptimal"*, it's in fact a very wrong anti-pattern. Actually, understanding that is even more important than the issue in the question you posted.

Answer (score 2):

A D3 simulation will start automatically. According to the documentation, `d3.forceSimulation`...

> Creates a new simulation with the specified array of nodes and no forces. If nodes is not specified, it defaults to the empty array. The simulator **starts automatically**. (emphasis mine)

The solution is stoping the simulation...

```
simulation.stop();
```

And then restarting it after the desired delay, for instance using `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  simulation.restart();
},2000);
```

Here is the original code you're building upon with a delay of 2 seconds:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <title>Force layout (with links)</title>
</head>

<style>
  circle {
    fill: cadetblue;
  }
  
  line {
    stroke: #ccc;
  }
  
  text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    fill: #666;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <svg width="400" height="300">
      <g class="links"></g>
      <g class="nodes"></g>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var width = 400,
      height = 300

    var nodes = [{
        name: 'A'
      },
      {
        name: 'B'
      },
      {
        name: 'C'
      },
      {
        name: 'D'
      },
      {
        name: 'E'
      },
      {
        name: 'F'
      },
      {
        name: 'G'
      },
      {
        name: 'H'
      },
    ]

    var links = [{
        source: 0,
        target: 1
      },
      {
        source: 0,
        target: 2
      },
      {
        source: 0,
        target: 3
      },
      {
        source: 1,
        target: 6
      },
      {
        source: 3,
        target: 4
      },
      {
        source: 3,
        target: 7
      },
      {
        source: 4,
        target: 5
      },
      {
        source: 4,
        target: 7
      }
    ]

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
      .force('link', d3.forceLink().links(links))
      .on('tick', ticked)
      .stop();

    setTimeout(function() {
      simulation.restart();
    }, 2000);

    function updateLinks() {
      var u = d3.select('.links')
        .selectAll('line')
        .data(links)

      u.enter()
        .append('line')
        .merge(u)
        .attr('x1', function(d) {
          return d.source.x
        })
        .attr('y1', function(d) {
          return d.source.y
        })
        .attr('x2', function(d) {
          return d.target.x
        })
        .attr('y2', function(d) {
          return d.target.y
        })

      u.exit().remove()
    }

    function updateNodes() {
      u = d3.select('.nodes')
        .selectAll('text')
        .data(nodes)

      u.enter()
        .append('text')
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name
        })
        .merge(u)
        .attr('x', function(d) {
          return d.x
        })
        .attr('y', function(d) {
          return d.y
        })
        .attr('dy', function(d) {
          return 5
        })

      u.exit().remove()
    }

    function ticked() {
      updateLinks()
      updateNodes()
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So help me understand... In what order is the code executed? Does it hit the simulation first, then get to .stop() and immediately stop it before it starts iterating? Then does it proceed to setTimeout(), wait 2 seconds, at which point the simulation kicks off again? If so, what stops the simulation from hitting .stop() again and stopping on the second time around?

Comment: The simulation is stopped after being defined and restarted in the setTimeout. Why would it hit stop again?